# spring-kafka: RetryTopicConfiguration with custom names for retry and dead letter topics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have supplied a bean for retry topic config:

```java
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration kafkaRetryTopicConfig(...) {
  return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
      .newInstance()
      .fixedBackOff(...)
      .maxAttempts(..)
      .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
      .doNotRetryOnDltFailure()
      .listenerFactory(factory)
      .create(template);
}
```

I have also defined a bean for retry topic names provider factory:

```java
// Need this because it is not just retry/DLT topic suffix but the entire name is configurable and specified in the configuration.
@Bean
public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory retryTopicNamingProviderFactory() {
  return new RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {
    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {
      return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {
        @Override
        public String getTopicName(String topic) {
          // NOTE: The retry and dead letter topic names come from config.
          // Like to create different names for retry and dead letter topics.
          // TODO: But how to distinguish which name I should return here!
          return *******;
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Two-part question:

a. Spring does not seem to correlate the beans. It is processing `kafkaRetryTopicConfig` bean but is not using the `retryTopicNamingProviderFactory` and custom topic names. It takes the default naming (`.retry` and `.deadLetter`). Is there any bean or component that I should declare so that the custom naming provider is picked up?

b. As indicated (`TODO`) in the code above, how do I distinguish whether `createRetryTopicNamesProvider` is called for retry or dead letter topic naming? I [**see**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.java#L22) that `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory` handles naming for both retry and dead letter topics.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies), the framework provides a `properties` object which you can inspect to find out whether you are on a `main`, `retry` or `dlt` topic, as well as the configured `suffixes` for the topic:

```java
public class CustomRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(
                DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {

        if(properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties);
        }
        else {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

                @Override
                public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                    return "my-prefix-" + super.getTopicName(topic);
                }

            };
        }
    }

}
```

You also have access to the original `topic` name, and the `super.getTopicName(topic)` method that will give you the suffixed topic name.

You should be able to use this information to return the topic name you'd like.

If this isn't enough customization for your use case, please provide more details on how you need to configure the topic names.

EDIT: Also, please inform the `Spring Kafka` version you're using - for version `2.9.x` and above the `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory` bean configuration is no longer supported.

EDIT 2: Addressing your comments, you should be able to tell the retry topic by using `!properties.isMainTopic() && !properties.isDltTopic()`. You can open a feature request in the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka) if you'd like an explicit `isRetryTopic()` method.

From what I understand about your requisites, you should be able populate a `map` where the key would be the topic name and type and the value is the configured topic name, and use that to return the proper name in the `RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory`.

The components' configuration system for this feature was changed in `2.9`, and a decision was made to enforce the [Experimental API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic) disclaimer and not support the legacy mode anymore. This doesn't change the `RetryTopicConfiguration` beans, just the bean-based component configurations. For `2.8` you should keep using the bean-based approach though.

You might want to consider upgrading to `2.9` though since it has a better configuration system in place for this feature, besides other improvements overall. This version is not attached to `Spring Boot`'s train and must be overridden manually.

The logic in [RetryTopicBootstrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/b6b4c1aee65e9d219db6d56ffc9342b871126c04/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicBootstrapper.java#L93-L102) that handles this in `2.8.x` is pretty straightforward - if there's a declared bean implementing this interface it should be fetched. Perhaps you can add a breakpoint there and make sure your bean is being considered.

Please let me know if that works for you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tomaz, yes, I saw the documentation and using the above factory. However, the factory and the names are not picked up by Spring. Also couldn't find a isRetryTopic() to check if it is a retry topic.

In my case, The names are not related to the main topic name, don't ask me why :( They come from config.

Using spring-kafka 2.8.8. If RTPNPF is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to your comment, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Tomaz. Your suggestion works! So I created a vanilla  [project](https://github.com/vivekragunathan/pearl) with spring and Kafka as a demonstration and also for other dev to start from this as a template. The project captures everything I was trying to do (so far ) with spring+Kafka, particularly your and @Gary's answers.

The part I got wrong with the above factory is I declared it as a bean to share implementation. I had to adjust a bit to declare it as a component.

Comment: We are back at square 1. We are now on spring boot 3, and spring-kafka transitively is 3.0.1. Happy to bump spring-kafka to the latest if need be.

Tried the suggestion in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2654) issue but no luck

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153219/retrytopicnamesproviderfactory-with-spring-kafka-3-0-10/77153242