# RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory with Spring-Kafka 3.0.10

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I implemented a non-blocking retry for my kafka app using Spring-Kafa 2.7. I needed a custom topic name for the DLT so RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory was used. The retry process worked as expected with this version. Recently the app was migrated to Spring Kafka 3.0.10 and now the default DLT is used. It appears the RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory is ignored now. I found a post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284479/spring-kafka-retrytopicconfiguration-with-custom-names-for-retry-and-dead-lette) that claims that:
In 2.9.x and above the RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory bean configuration is no longer supported.
Is there an equivalent or alternate method to configure a custom DLT name for retryable topic using Spring-Kafka 3.0.10 ? I looked at RetryTopicConfigurer but I need the entire name changed not just the suffix so I don't believe this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use the  RetryTopicConfigurationSupport https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicConfigurationSupport.html

Comment: Correct - docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies

Comment: Another example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723808/send-kafka-retryable-message-to-one-topic-via-spring-retry/75733513#75733513

Comment: After subclassing RetryTopicConfigurationSupport and overriding createComponentFactory  the dlt is using the correct topic name ( yay!) however the app is logging : "threw an error at topic mytopic-retry and won't be retried. Sending to DLT with name mytopic_dead." So the configured retry cycle is being skipped and the message goes directly to the DLT .  Is there any other configuration needed? Should I override other methods is RetryTopicConfigurationSupport ? Thanks

Comment: It depends on the exception type; some exceptions (such as message conversion etc) are considered fatal and not retried. If something else is happening; ask a new question showing your code, config, logs etc.

Comment: will do, thanks